# Can Pokémon Home be used to transfer the Mew into a new game of Let's Go?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go, pokemon-home

When *Pokémon Let's Go! Pikachu/Eevee* was released, a special edition included the Pokéball controller. This controller contained a Mew, which could be transferred to the game.

Once the Mew was transferred to a game, it was no longer in the controller and starting a new game meant losing the Mew.

Now that *Pokémon Home* has been released, does that still hold true? Or would it be possible to start a new game and keep the Mew by doing the below?

1. Transfer the Mew from *Let's Go!* to *Home*
2. Start a new game on *Let's Go!*
3. Transfer the Mew back into the new game of *Let's Go!*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are able to move Mew (or any Pokémon for that matter, except your starter) from Let’s Go into Pokémon Home. Once Mew is in Pokémon Home, you are free to start a new game and move it back into your game.

Pokémon Home is tied to your Nintendo account, not your save file. My friend recently moved all of his Pokémon Home, deleted his save file (on both Shield and Lets Go Eevee), started new games, and was able to move his Pokémon from Home into his new save files.

Due note though: If you move Mew into Pokémon Sword or Shield, Mew will no longer be able to be moved back into Let’s Go.

> You can move Pokémon back and forth between Pokémon: Let’s Go, Pikachu! and Pokémon: Let’s Go, Eevee! or into Pokémon Sword and Pokémon Shield.
>
> Once a Pokémon from Pokémon: Let’s Go, Pikachu! or Pokémon: Let’s Go, Eevee! is moved to Pokémon Sword or Pokémon Shield, it cannot be returned to its original game!
>
> [Pokemon.com](https://home.pokemon.com/en-us/move/)